# Gnome-sushi is not working in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial

Tags: 16.04, gnome, lubuntu, previews, gnome-sushi

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial version. I tried to use gnome-sushi to preview files from PCmanFM file manager which comes built in with Lubuntu.

Hitting spacebar opens the file in the allocated application automatically (even before installing gnome-sushi). After installing sushi, hitting spacebar doesn't make any difference.

Any idea how to turn on Preview Mode instead of opening the file in respective applications?

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Could you please cite some documentation that suggests it should work like that? GNOME sushi is for Nautilus, afaik it's *not* supposed to work with PCmanFM.